# Проблемы кроссбраузерности scrollby js

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Ребята такая проблема

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1);
console.log(window.pageYOffset);
window.scrollBy(0, 2);
console.log(window.pageYOffset);
window.scrollBy(0, 3);
console.log(window.pageYOffset);
```

В консоле у себя виже такое

```
1
3
6
```

В консоле у других пишет такое

```
0.80000000xxx // коеф. типа 0.8 как узнать коеф.?
0.24000000xxx
0.48000000xxx
```

Что за прикольчики?)

Comment: проверь масштаб

Comment: Знаю только что у меня экран 1366 а у друга 1900

Comment: важен не экран, а есть ли масштабирование страницы. Судя по всему, у друга стоит масштаб: 125%

Comment: а как сделать что бы при разных масштабах работало, или узнать маштаб?

Comment: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/2881286)